# How can I wrap the input if the chips takes 80% of its space

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, chips

I am using Chips in a input with material UI, I need to wrap the input down when chips takes most of the space (ex. 80%), and chips to be on top and wrapping!

```
<MDInput
                  value={inputValue}
                  error={!!errors.tags}
                  onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)}
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                  onBlur={handleBlurChanges}
                  label="Press enter to add tag"
                  name="tags"
                  helperText={errors?.tags}
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment
                        sx={{
                          minHeight: "40px",
                        }}
                        spacing={1}
                        position="start"
                      >
                        {chips.map((chip, index) => (
                          <Chip
                            sx={{
                              marginRight: "5px",
                            }}
                            key={index}
                            label={chip}
                            onDelete={handleDelete(chip)}
                            variant="outlined"
                            onBlur={handleBlurChanges}
                          />
                        ))}
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aSw9.png)

Comment: Can you please include a runnable snippet? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

This can fix your issue now, by adding `sx={{marginLeft: '5px', marginRight: '5px', }}` to sx prop of Chip. To get more space after tags

Here is the working example: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-deyfbv?file=demo.js)

Comment: I just added a screenshot with the input how I want to be after tags takes the most of the space

Comment: Hi, you can see my edit if anything else then let me know.

Comment: I tried it but it is not the issue on margin. tags goes out of the input instead of wrapping.

Comment: can you share a working code example?